# Selenium cannot find Xpath when "xmlns" attribute is included

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath

Basically I'm trying to process the following HTML using the Xpath of Selenium:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<a>Public Profile</a>
</html>
```

I'm using the following selector:

```
//a[text() = 'Public Profile']
```

Seems simple enough, however, according to Selenium it returns 0 matches.
I have tried in the online xpath tester as well:

> http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester

and it doesn't return any results neither.
The strange thing is that when I remove the

> xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"

-attribute it finds the match without a problem.

Can anyone explain to me why the xmlns tag makes the Xpath query fail?

On a sidenote, my C# selenium-xpath query looks the following:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[text() = 'Public Profile']"))
```

EDIT: A link I found which explains what's going on nicely:

> [XML element has namespace, my XPATH does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981312/xml-element-has-namespace-my-xpath-does-not-work?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: I’m still curious to see what actual code you’re running that causes this. My understanding from talking with some webdriver friends is that webdriver basically just passes its xpath evaluation off to  `document.evaluate(…)` in whatever browser you’re testing with. And when I run `document.evaluate("//a[text() = 'Public Profile']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)` a browser, it works as expected even with that `xmlns` on the `html` element. Please try it directly in a browser and lemme know if you see the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as XML/XPath processing goes, the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` part puts the `html` element into an XML namespace.

And the `a` element inherits that namespace. And the `//a[text() = 'Public Profile']` XPath expression will only match an *un-namespaced* `a` element.

`//a[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'][text() = 'Public Profile']` is one way to make it match.

`//*[name()='a'][text() = 'Public Profile']` is another way.

And `//*[text() = 'Public Profile']` is yet another way (assuming you already know that’ll get the `a` element you want, and not some other element).

Comment: So Selenium reads the HTML as XML?
But isn't HTML XML anyways? I don't see how this could cause any issues Selenium/Xpath-wise.

Comment: I don’t know about how Selenium, specifically, handles this. But XPath in general does pay attention to namespace declarations. That’s what the XPath spec requires.

Comment: Ahh I see! If anyone else is wondering, I found this answer which furthermore explains the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981312/xml-element-has-namespace-my-xpath-does-not-work?answertab=oldest#tab-top