# xpath for xml document with varying depth

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an xml document where there is fixed structure but depth is varying for example :-

> 1. It has main node `<project>`.
> 2. it has child node `<namespace>` that may be repeated multiple times. And there may come some new tags before or after `<namespace>`.

```
<project>
 <newtag>
 <namespace>
   <namespace>
     ..........
   </namespace>
 </namespace>
 </newtag>
</project>
```

> 3. After multiple namespace there are two more tags of my interest `<querySubject>` and `<queryItem>`

I am searching for a text in queryItem tag using a particular XPATH :-

```
/project/namespace/namespace/querySubject/queryItem[contains(., 'searchTerm')]/ancestor-or-self::*/name
```

My Xpath is working fine for a particular structure given below :-

```
<project>
<namespace>
        <name locale="en">Test</name>
        <lastChanged>2016-01-12T12:42:46</lastChanged>
            <namespace>
            <name locale="en">Database Layer</name>
                <querySubject status="valid">
                <name locale="en">qskxyz</name>
                    <queryItem>
                    <name locale="en">qixyz</name>
                        <hello>searchTerm</hello>
                    </queryItem>
                </querySubject>
            </namespace>
 </namespace>
 <namespace>
        <name locale="en">Test</name>
        <lastChanged>2016-01-12T12:42:46</lastChanged>
            <namespace>
            <name locale="en">Database Layer</name>
                <querySubject status="valid">
                <name locale="en">qsxyz</name>
                    <queryItem>
                    <name locale="en">myName</name>
                        <hello>...Hi there..</hello>
                    </queryItem>
                </querySubject>
            </namespace>
 </namespace>
 </project>
```

but not working if there is change as described in above points. Any suggestion

**EDIT 1.**

There was some miss in my observation

My actual project tag is

```
<project containsDynamicContent="false" xmlns="http://www.developer.cognos.com/schemas/bmt/60/7" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.developer.cognos.com/schemas/bmt/60/7 BMTModelSpecification.xsd">
```

However in dev I am taking simple `<project></project>`

This is affecting and my Xpath is not working.
Any suggestion  I tried below Xpath but this too is not working and I can not change my xml tag..
I have already tried this xpath :-

```
//namespace//querySubject/queryItem[contains(.,'searchTerm')]/ancestor-or-self::*/name
```

Comment: *"I am searching for a text in queryItem tag using a particular XPATH"* > but your xpath expression selects all `name` nodes that are ancestors (or self) starting from the `queryItem` you select. That's contradictory.

Comment: yes, I am serching for text and then returning all ancestor names to track it down

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML element has namespace, my XPATH does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981312/xml-element-has-namespace-my-xpath-does-not-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the XPath expression is:

```
/x:project//x:namespace//x:querySubject/x:queryItem[contains(.,'searchTerm')]/ancestor-or-self::*/x:name
```

Then you need to associate the namespace `http://www.developer.cognos.com/schemas/bmt/60/7` with the prefix `x`.

---

I'm going to leave you with a snippet in Java (1.7) as an example. This registers a `NamespaceContext` with the XPath expression, which resolves a namespace for a prefix (`x` in this case). The snippet is a bare-bone example, it doesn't even check which prefix is passed to [`NamespaceContext.getNamespaceURI`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext.html#getNamespaceURI%28java.lang.String%29). Typical implementations use a map to map the URI to a prefix.

Other development environments should have similar functionality.

---

```java
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class XPathInXmlns {
    private static final String xml=
"<project containsDynamicContent=\"false\" xmlns=\"http://www.developer.cognos.com/schemas/bmt/60/7\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.developer.cognos.com/schemas/bmt/60/7 BMTModelSpecification.xsd\">"+
"   <namespace>"+
"           <name locale=\"en\">Test</name>"+
"           <lastChanged>2016-01-12T12:42:46</lastChanged>"+
"               <namespace>"+
"               <name locale=\"en\">Database Layer</name>"+
"                   <querySubject status=\"valid\">"+
"                   <name locale=\"en\">qskxyz</name>"+
"                       <queryItem>"+
"                       <name locale=\"en\">qixyz</name>"+
"                           <hello>searchTerm</hello>"+
"                       </queryItem>"+
"                   </querySubject>"+
"               </namespace>"+
"    </namespace>"+
"    <namespace>"+
"           <name locale=\"en\">Test</name>"+
"           <lastChanged>2016-01-12T12:42:46</lastChanged>"+
"               <namespace>"+
"               <name locale=\"en\">Database Layer</name>"+
"                   <querySubject status=\"valid\">"+
"                   <name locale=\"en\">qsxyz</name>"+
"                       <queryItem>"+
"                       <name locale=\"en\">myName</name>"+
"                           <hello>...Hi there..</hello>"+
"                       </queryItem>"+
"                   </querySubject>"+
"               </namespace>"+
"    </namespace>"+
" </project>";

    private static final String xpathExpr=
"/x:project//x:namespace//x:querySubject/x:queryItem[contains(.,'searchTerm')]/ancestor-or-self::*/x:name/text()";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
                @Override
                public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
                    return null;
                }
                @Override
                public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
                    return null;
                }
                @Override
                public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
                    return "http://www.developer.cognos.com/schemas/bmt/60/7";
                }
            });
            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpathExpr);
            NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)),XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for( int i = 0; i != nodeList.getLength(); ++i )
                System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getNodeValue());
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Test
Database Layer
qskxyz
qixyz
```

Comment: I think  I am missing something in xml, because it doesn't work.. will update after finding

Comment: @user2816085 I tested with your xml, added random elements before and after the namespace element, inserted multiple additional namespaces... works for me.

Comment: So this question becomes duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981312/xml-element-has-namespace-my-xpath-does-not-work

Comment: @user2816085 Updated with an example in Java.