# XPATH: Count Preceding Elements Within Ancestor Nodes

Tags: xml, xpath, counting

I'm having trouble working with XPATH and could use some guidance. I've used the w3schools tutorial - and it's not advanced enough to help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. (I anticipate needing to use XPATH more in the future - so referrals to good tutorials or books would also be appreciated).

I am working on a book that has lists with optional titles. If the listTitle is used, I would like to pre-pend a list number to the title concatenates the chapter and the list number (based on listTitle). Lists that do not contain listTitle should not increment the list counter.

Here's an example xml file with the desired results shown:

```
<chapter><title>Chapter 1></title>
    <para>Para text.</para>
    <ul><listTitle>List 1-1</listTitle> .... </ul>

    <section><title>Section 1.1</title>
    <ol> .... </ol>
    <ol><listTitle>List 1-2</listTitle> ... </ol>
    </section>

    <ol><listTitle>List 1-3</listTitle> ... </ol>
    <ul><listTitle>List 1-4</listTitle> ... </ul>
</chapter>

<chapter><title>Chapter 2></title>
    <para>Para text.</para>
    <ul><listTitle>List 2-1</listTitle> .... </ul>

    <section><title>Section 2.1</title>
    <ol> .... </ol>
    <ol><listTitle>List 2-2</listTitle> ... </ol>
    </section>

    <ol><listTitle>List 2-3</listTitle> ... </ol>
    <ul><listTitle>List 2-4</listTitle> ... </ul>
</chapter>
```

However, the actual result varies slightly. My listTitle count doesn't start over at the chapter level... so the listTitles keep counting (that is, instead of List 2-1 I get List 2-5). I just can't figure out how to specify the chapter relationship to have the count reset at the chapter level.

My XPATH:

```
'concat("List ",count(../preceding::chapter)+1," - ",(count(preceding::*:ol/*:listTitle)
 + count(ancestor::*:ol/*:listTitle)+ count(preceding::*:ul/*:listTitle) 
 + count(ancestor::*:ul/*:listTitle))," ")'
```

Comment: What are you using to process your xpath? Are you using xpath as part of XSLT? (If so, [`xsl:number`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#number) would be very helpful.)

Comment: Hi Daniel - thanks for the insight. Unfortunately, I'm constrained to doing the count in a function within a css file for my deployment... it's pretty specific, and is exclusive to Oxygen XML Author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused, at least in part, to xmlns issues.

This StackOverflow article helped: [XML element has namespace, my XPATH does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981312/xml-element-has-namespace-my-xpath-does-not-work)

The following code provides the correct list title count:

```
('concat("List ", count(preceding::chapter)+1,"-", for $i in
count(preceding::chapter) return ((count(//parent::basicDocument//
chapter[$i+1]//*[name() = "listTitle"] intersect preceding::* ) ) + 1 )," " )'
```