# How to transform xsl that XML document has namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, xml-namespaces

- I have XML document with namespace ns2 and default namespace:

```html
 <ns2:Products xmlns="https://www.schema.product.com" xmlns:ns2="https://www.schema.products.com">
        <Product ProductId="1">
            <ProductName> Hộp Hoa Hồng Trắng</ProductName>
            <ProductPrice>550000</ProductPrice>
            <ProductImage>https://dienhoa24gio.net//assets/upload/product/20-09-2015/hop-hoa-hong-trang-1442711392/274_default.jpg</ProductImage>
        </Product>
        <Product ProductId="2">
            <ProductName>An Lành</ProductName>
            <ProductPrice>780000</ProductPrice>
            <ProductImage>https://dienhoa24gio.net//assets/upload/product/17-10-2015/an-lanh-1445039808/274_default.jpg</ProductImage>
        </Product>
    </ns2:Products>
```

And xsl file to display table, use data of xml file

```html
 <xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='Products']">
        <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>name</th>
                        <th>price</th>
                        <th>image</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='Product']">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='ProductName']"/></td>
                       
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='ProductPrice']"/></td>
                        
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='ProductImage']"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
    </xsl:template>
```

- I import 2 file(xml and xsl) and run jsp

```html
<c:import url="test.xml" var="xmlDoc" charEncoding="UTF-8"/>
        <c:import url="test.xsl" var="xslDoc" charEncoding="UTF-8"/>
        <x:transform xml="${xmlDoc}" xslt="${xslDoc}"/>
```

But when run jsp page, data of row table is same i don't know

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>name</th><th>price</th><th>image</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Hộp Hoa Hồng Trắng</td><td>550000</td><td>https://dienhoa24gio.net//assets/upload/product/20-09-2015/hop-hoa-hong-trang-1442711392/274_default.jpg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Hộp Hoa Hồng Trắng</td><td>550000</td><td>https://dienhoa24gio.net//assets/upload/product/20-09-2015/hop-hoa-hong-trang-1442711392/274_default.jpg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Hộp Hoa Hồng Trắng</td><td>550000</td><td>https://dienhoa24gio.net//assets/upload/product/20-09-2015/hop-hoa-hong-trang-1442711392/274_default.jpg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Hộp Hoa Hồng Trắng</td><td>550000</td><td>https://dienhoa24gio.net//assets/upload/product/20-09-2015/hop-hoa-hong-trang-1442711392/274_default.jpg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Hộp Hoa Hồng Trắng</td><td>550000</td><td>https://dienhoa24gio.net//assets/upload/product/20-09-2015/hop-hoa-hong-trang-1442711392/274_default.jpg</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Please help me fix this bug, 
Thank you so much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML element has namespace, my XPATH does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981312/xml-element-has-namespace-my-xpath-does-not-work)

Comment: The namespaces do not seem to be part of the actual problem. Possibly you want to edit your title.

Answer (score 0):

Because you start everything with // it will search the whole document, so every time your for-each finds a product it will go and find the first element that matches ProductName instead of the ProductName in the current Product element.

Try the following xsl instead:

```
     <xsl:stylesheet 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0"><xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='Products']">
            <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <th>name</th>
                            <th>price</th>
                            <th>image</th>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='Product']">
                            <tr>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='ProductName']"/></td>

                                <td><xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='ProductPrice']"/></td>

                                <td><xsl:element name="img">
<xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='ProductImage']"/></xsl:attribute></xsl:element></td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </table>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the input of

```
<ns2:Products xmlns="https://www.schema.product.com" xmlns:ns2="https://www.schema.products.com">
        <Product ProductId="1">
            <ProductName> Hộp Hoa Hồng Trắng</ProductName>
            <ProductPrice>550000</ProductPrice>
            <ProductImage>https://dienhoa24gio.net//assets/upload/product/20-09-2015/hop-hoa-hong-trang-1442711392/274_default.jpg</ProductImage>
        </Product>
        <Product ProductId="2">
            <ProductName>An Lành</ProductName>
            <ProductPrice>780000</ProductPrice>
            <ProductImage>https://dienhoa24gio.net//assets/upload/product/17-10-2015/an-lanh-1445039808/274_default.jpg</ProductImage>
        </Product>
    </ns2:Products>
```

It gives me the output of

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>price</th>
      <th>image</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> Hộp Hoa Hồng Trắng</td>
      <td>550000</td>
      <td>https://dienhoa24gio.net//assets/upload/product/20-09-2015/hop-hoa-hong-trang-1442711392/274_default.jpg</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>An Lành</td>
      <td>780000</td>
      <td>https://dienhoa24gio.net//assets/upload/product/17-10-2015/an-lanh-1445039808/274_default.jpg</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I solved this bug, 
If I want to add this link of image to <img src=" "/>

Comment: Change the line getting the image url to <xsl:element name="img">
<xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='ProductImage']"/></xsl:attribute></xsl:element>  to build up an img element with a src attribute. I have eddited the answer to reflect htis.